# Internal Server Error due to empty_like method already has a docstring

Tags: django, python-3.x, numpy, django-rest-framework

Currently I am facing a problem. Ok let me share it.

I have deployed this project into server `(apache2)` which is working fine as well as  all operation work successfully. But suddenly it's getting `Internal server error` basically when login. When I have downloaded the log it shows me `RuntimeError: empty_like method already has a docstring`. When I again restart my server it's again work smoothly. But I think this need a permanent solution. I also like to share the full trace of the log.

```
  Internal Server Error: /
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
      response = get_response(request)
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
      resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 498, in resolve
      for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
      patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
      return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/opt/python/my_project/my_project/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
      from apps.app_1 import urls as app_1_urls
    File "/opt/python/my_project/apps/app_1/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
      from .controller import main_controller
    File "/opt/python/my_project/apps/app_1/controller/main_controller.py", line 11, in <module>
      from .icebreaking_controller import IceBreakingController
    File "/opt/python/my_project/apps/app_1/controller/icebreaking_controller.py", line 1, in <module>
      from .base_controller import BaseController
    File "/opt/python/my_project/apps/app_1/controller/base_controller.py", line 4, in <module>
      from ..ai_model_handler.answer_validator import AnswerValidator
    File "/opt/python/my_project/apps/app_1/ai_model_handler/answer_validator.py", line 6, in <module>
      from ..ai_models.multiclass_cnn.multiclass_cnn_request import MultiClassCNNRequest
    File "/opt/python/my_project/apps/app_1/ai_models/multiclass_cnn/multiclass_cnn_request.py", line 11, in <module>
      import tensorflow as tf
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
      from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
      import numpy as np
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
      from . import core
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from . import multiarray
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 70, in <module>
      def empty_like(prototype, dtype=None, order=None, subok=None):
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 240, in decorator
      docs_from_dispatcher=docs_from_dispatcher)(implementation)
    File "/opt/python/ai_rest_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 204, in decorator
      add_docstring(implementation, dispatcher.__doc__)
  RuntimeError: empty_like method already has a docstring
```

Technology: `python3.6` `django 2.0.7`

Comment: This seems unrelated to Django. Two recent similar questions suggest the same fix to your WSGI configuration. Maybe you can try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377070/flaskuwsginginxcentos-error-import-module-numpy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537814/import-conflict-when-running-flask-app-with-apache-mod-wsgi-on-windows

Comment: @malberts Thanks for your suggestion. The link you have provided that is `uWSGI` configuration. But I have worked on `wsgi`. Any suggestion for `wsgi`?

Answer (score 2):

I did some R&D from the suggestion of my question comment with the issue of `single-interpreter=true` for *wsgi* configuration.
Have found a suggestion from the documentation
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIApplicationGroup.html?highlight=WSGIApplicationGroup#wsgiapplicationgroup

From the documentation.

> The WSGIApplicationGroup directive can be used to specify which application group a WSGI application or set of WSGI applications belongs to. All WSGI applications within the same application group will execute within the context of the same Python sub interpreter of the process handling the request.

It seems to me related to the `single-interpreter=true`.

And config the mod_wsgi by adding this line

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

I have observed the server log last one month wit this configuration.
And the server was running with out the above error.

Comment: Thank you so much for this insight! It helped me on a similar bug, with Flask under Python3.7+pandas (numpy specifically)+uWSGI (Same problem is mentioned here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/21225/).

I have only one question: When using the above Apache configuration, how is the performance? 

From what I understand, due to uWSGI multiple interpreters are used, which results in better performance (multiple GIL's, thus less latency for the end user). 

So the `single-interpreter` directive with GLOBAL scope, will disable the ability of WSGI to spawn multiple interpreters?